# unresolved includes in some c/c++ files in eclipse Luna

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

I am a java developer. Recently started to play with C/C++. For my C/C++ development i am using eclipse Luna. I am having 2 directories in my project src and test. **My source code is in C and my test code is in C++**. I am using google test framework which is in C++ and because of that all my test code is in C++. I have included some external includes in my project and added them under **GCC C Compiler/includes**.

The problem is that these includes are accessible in files under src directory but  none of the includes are accessible in files under test directory. I am having warning about unresolved includes. I have tried to rebuild the project, rebuild the index and tried every option under index but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours of struggle I have solved the problem.
Add your external includes in both C and C++ compiler under **C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> includes** and **C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C Compiler -> includes**.

Rebuild the index and all unresolved includes will be resolved. To compile it as C++ project you have to set Language Mappings under **C/C++ General -> Language Mappings**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add all sub-folders in the project to the GCC include path. It is done a bit different on different Eclipse implementations, but it should be something like:

**Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Compiler -> Includes**.

Comment: sorry i dont understand what you are saying. What I need to do with all sub folders ? and are you talking about sub folders under inc directories or are you talking about the project sub folders ?

Comment: @shan Project sub folders. You need to add them to the include path where gcc goes looking.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I created a C project. My source code is in C but I am using google test framework (C++) to test it. Because of that all my test files are C++ files and only C++ files are complaning. I think this is the problem. Any suggestion about this issue ?